# Django function that passes variables to other functions

Tags: django-urls

I have the following 4 lines of code that I keep reusing in my django views. I would like a function that passes the final value (All the objects of a logged in user) to my other functions and how to call that. As a fix, I have to keep using this lines in all my functions.

```
sessionkey = request.session.session_key
session = Session.objects.get(session_key=sessionkey)
uid = session.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id')
user = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=uid)
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want to do -- as I see it, you want to pass this information to a function from your view... or do you...?

Comment: yes, I want to pass the information of the logged in user to other functions in my view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_userprofile_from_session_via_request(request):
  sessionkey = request.session.session_key
  session = Session.objects.get(session_key=sessionkey)
  uid = session.get_decoded().get('_auth_user_id')
  user = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=uid)
  return user
```

Of course, I'm not sure why you wouldn't simplify this to:

```
def get_userprofile_from_session_via_request(request):
  user = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=request.session['_auth_user_id'])
  return user
```

Comment: how do i call the user.is_staff. When I try `get_userprofile_from_session_via_request.user.is_staff` I get an error stating 'function' object has no attribute 'user'

Comment: It's a function. Call it, passing the `request` from the view as the first argument.